# Conditional Formating in Excel comparing dates between cells

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have 2 columns that have conditional formatting to compare the Day and Time in the cells.

M compares against K,
N compares against L

In both cases, if the cell data is <= then it should return Green. If > then it should return Red.

I have done 45 other data entries and every day and time worked perfectly until the last row.  They are the only cells showing Friday.  Any ideas why this is happening?

I have an example in the images showing the row just above it where the formatting is working just fine.

Also, the format for the cells is dddd hh:mm.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I did a quick validation formula to see if N46 > L46, produce Y and it does flag as being greater for some reason.
[image]

Comment: is K46 a full date? Could it be that it from "next" week compared to M46?

Comment: K46 and L46 are xlookup formulas referencing another table to generate those Day/Times.  I double checked the those cells and the reference data and it is the format I listed dddd hh:mm.  I will add a picture of the reference formula and data format if that helps too.

Comment: I am not interested in the formatting but in the plain *date* - compared to the *date* in column M and N.

Comment: Its not a date in those cells.  So M46 actually has Monday 02:18 typed into the cell, same for N.

Comment: Ok - then your logic won't work: if those values are no dates, they are compared as strings and then the alphabet counts: M > F; regarding your new validation: T > F is also true

Comment: If you have Excel 365 current channel you can try: `=--TEXTAFTER(N46," ") > --TEXTAFTER(L46," ")` - this will compare the hour part only

Comment: That makes sense.  Got to rework my setup.  Thank you.

Comment: So your formula works for the times just fine but its flagging days that shouldn't be since its skipping the day.  I haven't seen the TEXTAFTER used before and is an interesting idea.

Comment: Is there a way to convert the text FRIDAY to the date of that given week?

Answer (score 0):

You will need helper columns to retrieve a date from your strings.

You can use this formula - maybe it makes sense to create a LAMBDA function from that (look for according tutorials) - where A3 is the cell with your data (e.g. Friday 11:30)

```vb
=LET(d,A3,
day,TEXTBEFORE(d," "),time,TEXTAFTER(d," "),
weekdays,{"Monday";"Tuesday";"Wednesday";"Thursday";"Friday";"Saturday";"Sunday"},
weekdayIndex, MATCH(day,weekdays,0), (TODAY() + (weekdayIndex-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2) +1) ) + time)
```

Then you can use the helper columns for your conditiona formatting.

(I tried: it is not possible to use a LAMBDA function as formula for the conditional formatting).